# Kafka-node only works on Zookeeper port (2181)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

When I try to make a new `KafkaClient` I must specify the IP of my node and the port 2181 on Node.js.

I am making heavy inserts into my DB through Kafka and everytime I leave it run overnight I get `CONNECTION_LOSS[-4]` errors which must have to do with Zookeeper.

On other languages the Kafka port 9092 works for producing/consuming, just not on `Node.js`.

How can I fix this issue and avoid these connection errors, and use port 9092 rather than 2181?

Comment: Inserts into what database? Have you heard of Kafka Connect framework?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Kafka are you using ?

Prior to 0.9.0 the connection to Zookeeper from a consumer was needed because the consumer used Zookeeper for saving offsets.

Starting from `0.9.0`, the offsets are saved in a specific topic named `__consumer_offsets` and for this reason the only connection the client needs is to Kafka brokers (the bootstrap ones) on the port `9092` you are talking about.

In any case remember that Kafka needs connection on Zookeeper on port `2181` for doing all the other stuff (controller election, topic information and so on).

It's not about using port `9092` instead of `2181`.